# 2sxc: Accordion App - Open / Close section state regarding of desktop / mobile view

Tags: mobile, accordion, 2sxc

Because 2sxc Accordion App have in settings "Initially open/close" switch for each section, I wonder is it possible to tweak this in some way to get Accordion initially open for desktop page view and initially closed for mobile page view?
It would save space / scrolling time and look more appealing in mobile page view.

Or just take this as idea for some next version of this App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be fairly easy to do. I suggest you do the following:

1. The toggle for open/close could be replaced with the boolean-tristate, so you have a true (open), false (closed) and null (automatic).
2. Then adjust the razor code a bit to make this happen.

If you got it to work, it would be awesome if you could contribute your code to the app in github: https://github.com/2sic/app-accordion

Comment: It looks like I will have to try... :-)

Comment: best of luck :)